# Android OPenGL+ XML

Tags: java, android, xml, animation, opengl-es

I make animations with class view, but view hangs and I was offered make animations in OpenGL ES. 
My animation located on 1/4 screen and I integrated class in XML.

I did XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:baselineAligned="false">


        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#bbf"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            .
            .
            .
        </ScrollView>



        <ru.dima_n.elem.Anim
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/game_view"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:onClick="OnClickAnim"
            android:background="#000"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Now I do MainActivity:

```
package ru.dima_n.opengl;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    GLSurfaceView glSurfaceView;
    nRender renderer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }
}
```

Now I do class nRender :

```
public class nRender implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer
{
    GLSurfaceView glSurfaceView;

    public nRender()
    {

    }

    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 glUnused) { // Отрисовка кадра

        Random rnd = new Random();

        GLES20.glClearColor(((float)rnd.nextInt(2)/2.0f), ((float)rnd.nextInt(2)/2.0f), ((float)rnd.nextInt(2)/2.0f), 1.0f);
        Log.e("test","color");
        GLES20.glClear( GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT ); 
    }

    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 glUnused, int width, int height) { 

        GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

    }

    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 glUnused, EGLConfig config) { 

    }
}
```

And I make class Anim in it cause nRender. And Anim integrated in XML

```
public class Anim extends View
{
    GLSurfaceView glSurfaceView;
    nRender renderer;

    public Anim(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);

        try{    
            glSurfaceView = new GLSurfaceView(context);

            glSurfaceView.setEGLContextClientVersion(2);

            renderer = new nRender();

            glSurfaceView.setRenderer(renderer); 

            glSurfaceView.setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_CONTINUOUSLY); glSurfaceView.requestRender(); )

            Log.e("success", "success");

        }catch(RuntimeException e){
            Log.e("error","error");
        } 

    }
}
```

XML:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#000"/>

<ru.dima_n.opengl.Anim
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/game_view"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:background="#ff0360ff"

/>
```

I get Log "success", but animation is not started in class nRender and I not get logs in class nRender

How can I make animation OpenGL ES in 1/4 screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Made it!

My Main class:

```
package ru.dima_n.opengl;

import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    GLSurfaceView glSurfaceView;
    nRender renderer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        glSurfaceView = new GLSurfaceView(this);

        try{    // пытаемся инициализировать OpenGL

            glSurfaceView.setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
            renderer = new nRender(this);
            glSurfaceView.setRenderer(renderer); 
            glSurfaceView.setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_CONTINUOUSLY); 
            glSurfaceView.requestRender(); )


            Log.e("удачно","3456");

        }catch(RuntimeException e){
            Log.e("error","error");
        } 

        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.openGL); // находим наш LinearLayout
        ll.addView(glSurfaceView); // добавляем ему ребенка


    }
}
```

nRender:

```
public class nRender implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer
{

    private Context cnx;

    public nRender(Context context) {
        this.cnx = context;
    }

    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 glUnused) { 

        Random rnd = new Random();

        GLES20.glClearColor(((float)rnd.nextInt(2)/2.0f), ((float)rnd.nextInt(2)/2.0f), ((float)rnd.nextInt(2)/2.0f), 1.0f);
        Log.e("test","color");
        GLES20.glClear( GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT ); 
    }

    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 glUnused, int width, int height) { 

        GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

    }

    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 glUnused, EGLConfig config) { 

    }
}
```

And XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#000"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/openGL"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        >
</LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

I think this might come in handy someone